# Contact form 7 is posting to a url instead of posting via ajx

Tags: wordpress, plugins, contact-form-7

I am using contact form 7 plugin here (http://www.brazendev4.com/Cadental/) on right side. When I press Submit button page posts back to a url and refreshes but normally it posts via ajax and page does not refreshes. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning on using ajax/js to process the form, you probably should have an empty action attribute in your form element.

e.g.

```
<form action="" method="post" class="wpcf7-form">
```

Try using the onclick attribute of the submit element to call your associated javascript function to process and post via ajax to "/Cadental/#wpcf7-f14-w1-o1".

e.g.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="MyJavascriptFunction(this.form)" class="wpcf7-form-control  wpcf7-submit text2">
```

My guess is that before your javascript has time to process the form the DOM is posting to action="/Cadental/#wpcf7-f14-w1-o1" and reloading the page.

I see you're using jQuery in your page, so it should be easy enough to use their serialize form function to process your form. 
http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is look at the other plugins or even the theme that you are using, making sure that nothing is conflicting with CF7 which is notorious for conflicting with other javascript you use.

Check out the [docs](http://contactform7.com/docs/) they might be able to help.

Otherwise, if the edit ability of the forms isn't important, I'd even suggest building your own form and submitting it via AJAX.

There are plenty of resources and tricks and tips around for doing this.